# Does the inverse color view on mac take up extra battery?

Tags: macos

Does the inverse color view (command, option, ctrl, 8) take up extra battery life on a mac? And if it does...is that extra life significant?

Comment: Heh, is this to settle a bet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wouldn't imagine this would consume a significant amount of battery life.  If the inverse color view is a background process continuously running then it might reduce battery life a bit - but I doubt this is the case and its just a setting that doesn't really add to the load of the computer.

Answer (score 2):

If you'd be using one of these *antique* CRT monitors darkening the contents of your display would really save a lot of power. On modern LCD monitors there should be no difference at all.

There is a site called [Blackle](http://blackle.com/) (a black google replacement) which claims to have saved a lot of power already, but I doubt that they are running their stats against LCDs.